# Ninject WebAPI dependency with a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I am trying to set up Ninject for the first time using [this little library](https://gist.github.com/odytrice/5842010).
I have a base controller which currently looks like this:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{

    // Private properties
    private IModelFactory factory;

    // Public properties
    public IServiceInterface Connection { get; private set; }
    public IModelFactory Factory { get { return this.factory ?? (this.factory = new ModelFactory()); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public BaseController()
    {

        // Get our database settings
        var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"].ToUpper();
        var type = (setting == "LIVE") ? ServiceInterface.ServerType.Azurerelay_live : ServiceInterface.ServerType.Azurerelay_test;

        try
        {

            // Apply to our public properties
            this.Connection = new ServiceInterface(type);

        } catch
        {

            // Throw a 401 error
            throw new HttpResponseException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use Ninject on this constructor, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the **ServiceInterface** because it requires a parameter.
I tried to bind the service like this:

```
// List and Describe Necessary HttpModules
// This class is optional if you already Have NinjectMvc
public class NinjectHttpModules
{
    //Return Lists of Modules in the Application
    public static NinjectModule[] Modules
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { new MainModule() };
        }
    }

    //Main Module For Application
    public class MainModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            //TODO: Bind to Concrete Types Here
            Kernel.Bind<IServiceInterface>().To<ServiceInterface>();
            Kernel.Bind<IFactory>().To<Factory>();
        }
    }
}
```

and changing my constructor to this:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{

    // Public properties
    public readonly IServiceInterface Connection;
    public readonly IModelFactory Factory;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public BaseController(IServiceInterface connection, IModelFactory factory)
    {

        try
        {

            // Apply to our public properties
            this.Connection = connection;
            this.Factory = factory;

        } catch
        {

            // Throw a 401 error
            throw new HttpResponseException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

But that won't work because the **ServiceInterface** requires a parameter to state if it is live or not.
Does anyone know how I can get this code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent reading configuration values from places like the `AppSettings` at runtime. Not only is there no need to read them more than once (performance), but scattering their use throughout the application has a profound effect on maintainability and reliability. Instead, move the retrieval of configuration values to the startup path of the application. This:

- Prevents having to read them over and over again, allows the application to fail fast when a value is missing.
- Improves testability because classes loose the dependency on the configuration system.
- Keeps access to those configuration values in one single location, making it much easier to change the application or the structure of the configuration files.

Your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) should look something like this:

```
public override void Load()
{
    var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"].ToUpper();
    var type = (setting == "LIVE")
        ? ServiceInterface.ServerType.Azurerelay_live
        : ServiceInterface.ServerType.Azurerelay_test;

    Kernel.Bind<IServiceInterface>().ToMethod(c => new ServiceInterface(type));
    Kernel.Bind<IModelFactory>().ToMethod(c => new ModelFactory());
}
```

Another thing is that you should Favor [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Base classes are a sign of design problems. So ditch the base class and inject `IModelFactory` and `IServiceInterface` into the constructors of concrete classes that require their use:

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IModelFactory modelFactory;
    private readonly IServiceInterface serviceInterface;

    public HomeController(IModelFactory modelFactory, IServiceInterface serviceInterface) 
    {
        this.modelFactory = modelFactory;
        this.serviceInterface = serviceInterface;
    }

    // actions here
}
```

Also prevent from doing anything in your constructors except storing incoming dependencies. You [injection constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). This includes things like throwing exceptions. Prevent throwing exceptions from constructors, because this makes [resolving your object graph unreliable](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

Refrain from using the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), make sure components only have [one constructor](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97), don't inject any [runtime data into them](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) and look out for [constructor over-injection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/20/RebuttalConstructorover-injectionanti-pattern/), since this is an indication of violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: You can also use Kernel.Bind<IServiceInterface>().To<ServiceInterface>().WithConstructorArgument("type", type); just in case your class has more than one parameter/dependency you then make sure the rest is also resolved automatically.